# MVCContrib Portable Areas Swf Embedded Resource

Tags: .net, embedded-resource, mvccontrib

I'm getting the error "The given key was not present in the dictionary." with a swf as an embedded resource in a MVCContrib portable area. When I remove the file from the assembly entirely I get a standard 404, so I'm pretty sure it's finding the file, just having issues returning it.

Images, scripts, styles, etc are working fine, even those in the same directory as the swf.

Do I need to specify the .swf file type somewhere to allow it to be retrieved from the assembly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this to work by modifying the MVCContrib source code. The embedded resources controller limits the types of resources allowed by mime type. I had to add the .swf mime type, now it works.